# How to enforce constraints between template and template template parameters in C++17

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I have the following code that compiles (GCC7, C++17):

```
template<typename T>
struct NDArrayHostAllocatorNew
{
    static T* allocate(std::size_t size) {
        return new T[size];
    }

    static void deallocate(const T* ptr){
        delete [] ptr;
    }
};

template<typename T, template<typename TT> typename Alloc>
class NDArrayHost
{
public:
    typedef Alloc<T> allocator_type;
    NDArrayHost(std::size_t size);
private:
    T* m_data;
};

template<typename T, template<typename TT> typename Alloc>
NDArrayHost<T, Alloc>::NDArrayHost(std::size_t size)
{
    m_data = allocator_type::allocate(size);
}
```

Here are my questions:

- If I use `T` instead of `TT` I get an error that one `T` shadows the other. OK fair enough, but in my case, I want `T` to be the same with `TT`. How can I enforce that? I guess I could use `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same` somehow? But in that case the code will become too hairy. Is there any less hairy solution for this?
- I barely see code with template template parameters. Am I doing something that is not considered a good practice?
- I don't really like the syntax of this solution. Is there a better way to do the same but with cleaner/simpler code?
- While the code with the template template parameters is big ugly, it is quite obvious to understand what this code does: It just allows the user to specify his/her own mechanism to allocate memory for `NDArrayHost` objects. Although this qualifies for a whole different/separate question: if you think that I am approaching the problem completely wrong, feel free to point me to a better solution (as long as is not very complex like `Thrust`.

Comment: "I want T to be the same with TT" This makes no sense. Your user supplies T for NDArrayHost. *You* inside NDArrayHost supply TT for Alloc. If you want TT be the same as T, just pass T as a parameter for Alloc.

Comment: TT is a dummy parameter, writing  "template<typename> typename Alloc" has the same effect. Also you can not use TT for any purpose, basically even something like template <typename T, template <typename TT> typename Alloc>
class NDArrayHost
{
  using UU = TT;
}; is illegal.

Comment: The question is about template-template and not related to the C++17 standard. You can compile this question and the answers I have seen so far with C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On way is to declare the base template in terms of types `T` and `Alloc` and then only provide a legal partial specialisation.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct NDArrayHostAllocatorNew
{
    static T* allocate(std::size_t size) {
        return new T[size];
    }

    static void deallocate(const T* ptr){
        delete [] ptr;
    }
};

/*
 * declare the base template in terms of T and allocator
 */
template<typename T, typename Alloc>
class NDArrayHost;

/*
 * only provide legal specialisations
 */
template<class T, template<class> class Alloc>
class NDArrayHost<T, Alloc<T>>
{
public:
    typedef Alloc<T> allocator_type;
    NDArrayHost(std::size_t size);
private:
    T* m_data;
};

template<class T, template<class> class Alloc>
NDArrayHost<T, Alloc<T>>::NDArrayHost(std::size_t size)
{
    m_data = allocator_type::allocate(size);
}
```

We could if we liked, add a specialisation to provide a diagnostic if the T's don't match:

```
/* specifically disallow illegal specialisations */
template<class T, class U, template<class> class Alloc>
class NDArrayHost<T, Alloc<U>>
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, U>(), "meh");
};
```

Testing...

```
int main()
{
    NDArrayHost<int, NDArrayHostAllocatorNew<int>> h(10);

    // fails with static assert
    // NDArrayHost<int, NDArrayHostAllocatorNew<double>> h2(10);
}
```